# No data passed using UnityWebRequest POST

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, post, unitywebrequest

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a MySQL database through php POST method to Unity.
But somehow, when I use the UnityWebrequest the post variable is always empty.

My C# script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class IDCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
int onlineID = -1;

readonly string urlCheckIdentifier = "http://www.mywebsite.php";

void Start(){
    if (Application.internetReachability != NetworkReachability.NotReachable){
        StartCoroutine("GetOnlineID");
    }
}

void SetID(int _id){
    onlineID = _id;
}

IEnumerator GetOnlineID(){
    // TEST NUMBER 2
    List<IMultipartFormSection> form = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("onlineid", "test"));

    /* THIS WAS ATTEMPT NUMBER 1
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("onlineid", "test");
    */

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(urlCheckIdentifier, form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError){
        Debug.Log("Error on upload");
    } else {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        DownloadData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<DownloadData>(www.downloadHandler.text);
        bool idFound = (data.succes == false)?false:true;

        if (!idFound){
            Debug.Log("Didnt work");
            Debug.Log(data.succes);
        } else {
            SetID(data.id);
            Debug.Log(onlineID);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My PHP script:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

// UNIQUE DEVIDE ID IS GIVEN FROM THE APP VIA POST METHOD
$onlineid = $_POST["onlineid"];

// CHECK IF ID EXISTS IN CURRENT USERS TABLE
$query = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE uniqueID='$onlineid'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

if($row){
    // IF ID WAS FOUND, RETURN JSON TO THE APP
    $dataArray = array('success' => true, 'error' => '', 'id' => $row[1], 'username' => $row[2], 'TESTuniqueIDPassed' => $onlineid);
} else {
    // ID WAS NOT FOUND, CREATING NEW ONE.
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO users(uniqueID) VALUES ('$id')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query2);

    // GETTING THE NEWLY CREATED ID FROM THE DB.
    $query3 = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE uniqueID='$id'";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query3);

    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);

    // RETURNING JSON WITH THE NEW ID
    $dataArray = array('success' => true, 'error' => '', 'id' => $row3[1], 'username' => $row3[2], 'TESTuniqueIDPassed' => $onlineid);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
//echo json_encode($dataArray);
echo $onlineid;
?>
```

As you can see I even tried to just echo the $onlineid which should be populated with the POST method from unity, but that's always returning an empty string.

I've tried google of course but most posts about this subject are pretty old.
The solution to add

```
www.chunkedTransfer = false;
```

in front of the yield return call is now depreciated, and another suggested solution was to put

```
www.useHttpContinue = false;
```

in front of the yield return also did nothing to solve the problem.

Anybody any ideas where to go from here?

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Have you tried using `WWWForm` as in the documentation? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt. I tried it afterwards with the IMultipartFormSection, but both resulted in a empty post

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple of things in the meantime while waiting for an anwser.
Stumbled upon an anwser myself so I will post it for the next person to have the same issue:

Your link should start with https instead of http, because Unity does not allow insecure links anymore.

Using MultipartFormDataSection still wont work, but WWWForm will!

Comment: "Unity does not allow insecure links" - can you please provide a link where you found this?

Comment: WWWForm also doesn't work for me